# How to get real time distance using an android phone

Tags: android, google-api, android-gps

I need to build an app, one of it's features is to calculate the distance travelled in real time. The path isn't essentially a straight line, it can be along curves.
I tried to use Google's Location API. Tracking down Location updates and cumulating the distance travelled from the last point of update to this new point.  But it isn't giving me accurate results. And because of the inaccurate location (sometimes). It gives me a metre or two distance travelled even when I'm sitting at the same place. Is there any other approach to measure distance using just an Android phone.
Also, I need to display the latitude and longitudes of the phone while it is being used

Comment: what is your expectation to a location api, how accurate you want to have it

Comment: The location api won't exceed the accuracy of GPS, which theoretically is 4m, but in practice closer to 15m. As @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ asked, how accurate do you need it?

Comment: @323go I need to measure a distance of around a kilometre with a maximum error of 3m. So, shall I go for some other device too? For instance, a tachometer. Since the measurement has to be while on a trolley. Which would be moving on a rail track.

Comment: Yes for that precision you'll need to go with another device. GPS even stationary has an error much higher than 3m, and that's before you deal with the issue of accurately polling GPS at reliable intervals. Apps that do this rely on a combination of sensors (gps+accelerometer and maybe even wifi) and even then do not have that level of precision.

Comment: If you *only* need to measure 1km, you might be able to get away with an IMU. A good IMU with a high enough sample rate should keep you within your accuracy requirements, and you can use GPS or another external trigger to augment absolute position of your trolley.

Comment: @323go No, I was just stating an example by saying 1 km. But actually, it would be more than that. May even be 30-40 kms at a stretch.

Comment: @KaranAsthana Have you found a solution? Please share if you did

Comment: @Royz Yeah I did come up with one. That us, using it along with a Raspberry Pi. Which had a Tachometer attached to it, which was used to measure the distance. Then, I made the raspberry pi a Router(Created a hotspot from it) and sent the data to the Phone via a Server port for the communication using tcP. Further, using things like threading etc. i could get the distance in real time.